# Adding Interaction Terms to MATLAB Multiple Regression

Tags: matlab, regression, linear-regression, standardized

I am currently running a multiple linear regression using MATLAB's `LinearModel.fit` function, and I am bit confused in regards to how to properly add interaction terms to the model by hand. As I am aware, `LinearModel.fit` does not standardize variables on its own, so I have been doing so manually.

So far, the way I have done it has been to

1. Standardize the observations for each variables
2. Multiply corresponding standardized values from specific variables to create the interaction terms and then add these new variables to the set of regression data
3. Run the regression

Is this the correct way to go about doing this? Should I standardize the interaction term variables also after calculating the 'raw' terms? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not to standardize interaction terms probably depends on what you intend to do with the model.  Standardization typically does not affect model performance as much as it allows for more straightforward model interpretation as your learned coefficients will be on similar scales. I suspect whether to do this or not is largely a matter of opinion. [Here is a relevant stats.stackexchange post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/when-should-you-center-your-data-when-should-you-standardize) that may help.

My intuition would be the same as how you have described your process so far.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So do you think I should standardize the interaction terms?

Comment: I would not standardize the interaction terms, no.  It would only make later analysis even more confusing in my opinion (i.e. standardized product of two standardized variables).